# On click open three taps in web browser

Tags: javascript

I have just been told to create a link that opens three tabs and I cant figure it out. The JavaScript I created opens two tabs only. Here is the code:

```html
<div id="g_image2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:760px; top:32px; width:149px; height:45px; z-index:49">
  <a href="javascript:{}" onClick="window.open('http://cent5.serverhostingcenter.com:2199/start/behyghgu/','radio_player', 'Width=82,Height=50,directories=0,hotkeys=0,location=0,menubar=0,personalbar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,toolbar=0');">
    onClick="window.open('http://cent5.serverhostingcenter.com:2199/start/behyghgu/','radio_player', 'Width=82,Height=50,directories=0,hotkeys=0,location=0,menubar=0,personalbar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,toolbar=0');">

    <img src="images/Fm101 banner.png" alt="" title="" border=0 width=145 height=43></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You won't get much help with a question like this. Take a look at [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other javascript question on here and try to supply as much information as possible in your question.

Comment: Your question is badly formatted, but I can kinda see what you are trying to do. Why not create a separate script tag or JS file and write your code there?

Answer (score 1):

Use a function

```js
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("playerlink").onclick=function(e) {
    e = e?e:window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    var w, 
        vid = this.getAttribute("data-vid").split(","),
        preFix = "http://cent5.serverhostingcenter.com:2199/start/";
    for (var i=0;i<vid.length;i++) {
       w = window.open(preFix+vid[i],"player_"+i,"width=82,height=50,resizable=0");
    }  
    if (w == null) {
       alert("Please allow popups");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <a href="pleaseturnonjs.html" id="playerlink" data-vid="behyghgu,behyghga,behyghgb">Click</a>
```